# Hide a div, when mouseout two divs, but not if you are hover one or another

Tags: javascript, jquery, fade, mouseenter, mouseleave

I have a two div with two id :

```
<div id="somediv">
many Content
</div>
<div id="result></div>
```

i want to make something like that :

```
$("#somediv").bind("mouseleave",function(){
$('#result').fadeOut();
});
$("#result").bind("mouseleave",function(){
$('#result').fadeOut();
});
```

But i don't want that result dissapears if if move my mouse on the
other div.
Is there a way to say : hide a div, when mouseout two divs, but not if
you are hover one or another ?
The divs are not exactly superposed in the page.
But They've got a common area.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$("#somediv,#result").mouseenter(function(){
    $('#result').stop().fadeOut();
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $('#result').stop().fadeIn();
});
```

Another thing you can do is wrap both divs by another div such as:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="somediv">
        Many Content
    </div>
    <div id="result"></div>
</div>
```

and set the event on the parent:

```
$('#container').mouseenter(function(){
    $('#result').stop().fadeIn();
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $('#result').stop().fadeOut();
});
```